How to give credit to a contributor who does not wish to be an author?
In a common (unfinished) paper written several months ago, one of the authors has moved away to a different group and is now working on something completely different. Due to some external reasons, the project we were all working on in our group (including this former colleague) was stopped, which explains why the paper remained unfinished.
Now it is time to finally bring whatever part of the project is finished to conclusion by publishing a paper about it. It is possible to do so. No further projects are foreseen with this former colleague.
I emailed around for consent and this colleague does not wish to be an author on this paper, no reasons are given. The colleague clearly contributed to the finished part of the project and credit is due. Normally this is done via authorship.
The colleague does not wish to be an author, what are my alternatives?

There are three possibilities and you need to explore. Normally they would be named in an acknowledgements section, perhaps with some detail about their earlier contributions. This is standard. Thesis advisors who make contributions are often such a case.
But it might also be the case that they don't wish to be named at all and you need to know this if it is true. In that case you can acknowledge an unnamed contributor (sort of an unindicted co-conspirator, if you like). It might be important to do this in a rare case to avoid plagiarism charges. It might (rare) be possible to name their role if not their personal name. Very awkward though.
The third possibility is that the person is an author but isn't giving permission for their work to be used at all. This can be a block on the paper as reputable publishers will honor such demands.  This seems unlikely here, but consider it. A major (major) re-write might be necessary.
You need to sort it out with that person. Being wrong is risky and potential misconduct.
